# how to divide screen into 3 trapezium buttons with swift?

Tags: swift, button, constraints, shapes

I have provided an image of how I would like it to appear but have no idea how to do it. Also if possible I would like to know how to constrain such awkward looking buttons to look good on all displays. Thank you all very much!!

[image: screen divided into 3 trapezium buttons]

Comment: I wouldn't use a button here. Go for a UIView and use it as a button.

Comment: Thanks i appreciate your reply, how would i turn the uiview into a trapezium shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enum CustomButtonType {
    case topLeft, topRight, bottom
}
let triangelHeight:CGFloat = 75
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    private var bgColor:UIColor = .white
    private var type:CustomButtonType = .topLeft

    init(frame:CGRect, bgColor:UIColor, type:CustomButtonType) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.bgColor = bgColor
        self.type = type
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        context.beginPath()
        switch type {
        case .topLeft:
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (rect.maxX), y: rect.maxY - triangelHeight))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (rect.minX), y: rect.maxY))
            break
        case .topRight:
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (rect.maxX), y: rect.maxY ))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (rect.minX), y: rect.maxY - triangelHeight))
            break
        case .bottom:
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY + triangelHeight))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY + triangelHeight))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (rect.maxX), y: rect.maxY ))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (rect.minX), y: rect.maxY ))
            break
        }
        context.closePath()
        context.setFillColor(bgColor.cgColor)
        context.fillPath()
    }
}
```

I have created buttons with frame you can use Autolayout.

```
let topBtnHeight:CGFloat = 400
let aBtn = CustomButton(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width / 2, height: topBtnHeight), bgColor: .green, type: .topLeft)
view.addSubview(aBtn)
let bBtn = CustomButton(frame: .init(x: view.frame.width / 2, y: 0, width: view.frame.width / 2, height: topBtnHeight), bgColor: .red, type: .topRight)
view.addSubview(bBtn)
let cBtn = CustomButton(frame: .init(x: 0, y: topBtnHeight - triangelHeight, width: view.frame.width , height: view.frame.height - topBtnHeight + triangelHeight), bgColor: .yellow, type: .bottom)
view.addSubview(cBtn)
```